# Ubuntu installation is successful but not getting an option to select OS

Tags: 18.04

I have installed Ubuntu on my laptop alongside with Windows 10 on Drive `D` (Windows is on Drive `C`). When installing Ubuntu it didn't ask any thing, it asked only whether you want to install alongside with Windows. I selected that option. There was message that the installation was successful. After restarting, it directly boots to Windows and it's not asking to select OS.

Comment: Did you configure grub2 after installing Ubuntu? The command is: `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 0):

You need to deactivate *Secure Boot* to see the boot option for Ubuntu.

To deactivate it:

1. Boot your laptop into BIOS mode.
2. Choose "Change Boot Mode Settings" or something like that, now hit enter.
3. Deactivate Secure Boot.

Your PC should automatically reboot, if it doesn't, boot into Ubuntu.
Then boot into BIOS mode again, and you should see the Ubuntu boot option.

*Secure Boot* prevents malware and unapproved operating systems from loading up at start-up, which is why Ubuntu successfully installs but *does not* actually show up as a boot option.